# Alarm not working

Tags: alarm

My Alcatel iPop Tracfone used to ring the alarm when the phone was completely turned off. It doesn't do that anymore. Would like to know why?
And how I can make that work again.
Thank you, Sandy

Answer (score 0):

I did figure out how to make my alarm work again. On an Alcatel iPop phone, you go to the clock app. Click on the alarm. Then click on the settings icon. Check the "Alarm in silent mode" option. This will allow your alarm to work even when your phone is turned totally off.